# React app always re-downloads images when using react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

I have `create-react-app` project with `react-router-dom`.

I have few Components what act like pages in SPA. All pages have same  component in them:

```
return (
      <img
        src="/images/logo.png"
        width={this.props.width}
        height={this.props.height}
        className="d-inline-block mb-2"
        alt="Logo"
      />
    );
```

Everytime I change component (view) with my `react-router-dom` the image gets re-downloaded from server (new request is sent):
[image]
It is same with FontAwesome svg icons.

How to preload or cache images in React to load them just once? I think image should not download everytime I change view.

Comment: If this component is the same on every page, then perhaps you can render it just once, outside of the pages just like described [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/nesting)

Answer (score 0):

Put your image inside **public/static** folder.

Comment: This makes it so it can't be imported as a ReactComponent and easily used.